# Putting multiple calculations into a for-loop that uses variables based on iteration number

Tags: c++, for-loop

What is the best way to organize the following into a for loop that iterates X times, but requires updating the variables (velocity, currentPose, targetPoint) depending on the iteration number?

```
velocity1 = computeVelocity(currentPose1, targetPoint1); 
velocity2 = computeVelocity(currentPose2, targetPoint2); 
... 
velocityX = computeVelocity(currentPoseX, targetPointX);
```

The for loop would ideally look something like this:

```
for (int i=0; i<X; i++)
{
  velocity_i = computeVelocity(currentPose_i, targetPoint_i);
}
```

Comment: This isn't bash, there's no way to (and no point in) naming variables with numbers like that to be iterated over. Instead stick the `currentPose`'s and `targetPoint`'s in an `std::vector` as you get them.

Comment: You're on the right track but missing the syntax.  It's `currentPose[i]` to access an array (or vector) element.

Answer (score 0):

Since for each `velocity`, there will be an associated (and possibly distinct) `currentPose` and `targetPoint`, one way to do it it to have all these variables as `std::vector`s, or `std::array` if you know at compile time how many items you will have to store. Then your loop could look like this:

```
for (int i=0; i<X; i++)
{
  velocity[i] = computeVelocity(currentPose[i], targetPoint[i]);
}
```

I don't think that wanting the `i` to be a part of the variables' name is doable (although there might be some way to do it using preprocessor macros and the `#` concatenation operator, I have not thought about it), nor would it be usual C++ code.

For a C++ programmer the `vector`/`array` approach is the more natural one.